# show different blade form for different category

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I have category column and I displayed it this way in my code:

```html
<Select id="colorselector" name="postercategorypop">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="true">pls select</option>

    @foreach($postercategories as $cat_id => $cat_name)
        <option value="{{ $cat_id }}">{{ $cat_name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</Select>
```

and I have to show different forms for each category when user clicks on category in option.

How can I have blade form for each category?
and how link category to that blade for show it under the select option?

Comment: You can do that using Javascript. Please study how [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) works.

Comment: u can do it by adding an onclick event to the options with parameter as cat_id then render page by using ajax call

Comment: can you write that code here ?

Comment: @sina This is not a "free developers platform", you still have to try writing the code yourself. Do some research online.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

1. write a form only with the category field, post in the same page and choose wich one form show by a switch case
2. do it with Livewire. Set category model and render only the category form
3. write a div container for each form with hide class. Onchange of you category select, show only the right form